# Can time series models be applied to synthetic data

Tags: time-series, simulation

I would like to know if time series necessarily have to contain real (measured) data or can it also contain synthetic data (e.g. from a simulation). Does it make sense to apply time series models, like MA or ARIMA on synthetic data?

I'd be happy if you would mind answering my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Applying time series techniques to simulated data is quite common, and it can be very enlightening indeed.

For example: pick an ARIMA model of reasonable order with well-behaved parameters, simulate it and apply some kind of automatic ARIMA fitter to the simulated series (like `forecast::auto.arima()` in R). How often will the original model be recovered? Answer: surprisingly rarely. It's simulations like these, where you *know* the ground truth, that can teach you a lot of humility.

Then again, to be honest, if a paper *only* applies its new method to simulated data, but not to real time series, I tend to lose interest. It's very easy to tweak a simulation in a way that supports your pet theory. With real data, not so much. (Yes, we can select datasets and overfit to the holdout data.)

So: applying methods to simulated data should be part of every time series analyst's toolbox. Among *other* tools.

---

Let us look at a little example. We will simulate $n=200$ data points from an ARIMA(1,1,1) process, with an AR(1) coefficient of $\phi_1=0.5$, an MA(1) coefficient of $\theta_1=-0.3$ and the default noise of $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$. We then apply `auto.arima()` to the simulated series and ask whether `auto.arima()` at least gets the *order* (1,1,1) right. We do this whole process 1,000 times:

```
require(forecast)
n_sims <- 1e3
n_obs <- 200
model_true <- list(ar=0.5,ma=-0.3,order=c(1,1,1))

correct <- rep(FALSE,n_sims)
pb <- winProgressBar(max=n_sims)
for ( ii in 1:n_sims ) {
    setWinProgressBar(pb,ii,paste(ii,"of",n_sims))
    set.seed(ii) # for reproducibility
    sim <- arima.sim(model=model_true,n=n_obs)
    model <- auto.arima(sim)
    correct[ii] <- isTRUE(all.equal(model$arma,c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0)))   
    # this corresponds to ARIMA(1,1,1), see ?arima
}
close(pb)
summary(correct)
```

It turns out that in just 105 cases did we even get the correct order. I think this teaches us something about the inherent difficulty in even identifying the correct ARIMA order.

Of course, if we increase the parameter values, reduce the noise or increase the length of the series, we would be right more often.

The next step would be not to pluck parameter values out of thin air, as I did here. Instead, we could take a time series that is "typical" for the application we have in mind. Fit an ARIMA model to it, and then use the *fitted* order, parameters and residual variance as inputs to this simulation, i.e., treat the fitted ARIMA model as if it were the true data generating process. You will still be surprised at how rarely such a ("realistic"!) DGP will actually be found by `auto.arima()`. (Which is the gold standard in ARIMA model fitting, I hasten to say.) And of course, you can do similar exercises with Exponential Smoothing and/or other time series methods.

And this is the reason why simulated series have their place in time series analysis.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your answer. What do you mean by "pick an ARIMA model" and "apply some kind of automatic ARIMA fitter to it"?. As far as I understand ARIMA is a time series model for predictions. How can you fit an ARIMA model to another ARIMA model?

Comment: Simulate a time series that follows $ARIMA(p, d, q)$ with specified coefficients. Then fit an ARIMA model to it and see if you get close to the right coefficients.

Comment: ARIMA is a data generating process, and `auto.arima()` attempts to find the correct order and to estimate the parameters. Let me edit a little example into my answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answers and help Dave and Stephan.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote the question itself (as in some sense having a very obvious answer), but then read this excellent answer and decided that both the question and the answer deserved an upvote instead. You didn't just stop with the obvious answer but instead provided important context, caveats, and examples.

Comment: @JohnColeman: thank you. It's comments like yours that motivate me to contribute here.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, it is common to test methods with synthetic data. I think doing so allows one to really focus on the strengths and weaknesses of a model. Then it is another question whether or not those tests and the synthetic data reflect real world scenarios well enough to make the method actually useful. But it has been certainly done.

As a reference, I can provide "A note on the Mean Absolute Scaled Error" by Philip Hans Franses ([link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.03.008)), but I'm sure there are plenty of similar papers.